How to merge two array using .map and .find by avoiding iterating twice
I have two arrays below. I am trying to merge conditions array based on customerLOB.code match. The problem is, I am getting the results added twice because the loop gets iterated twice. How can I avoid this. Any help is much appreciated.
Here based on the customerLOB code , if it matches, I am trying to get a single array which has the list of conditions(array of objects from both arrays). But instead of 3 results , I am getting 6 results.


const array1 = [
  {
    conditions: [
      {
        name: "xxx",
        id: "1",
      },
    ],
    customerLOB: {
      code: "A1",
    },
  },
  {
    conditions: [
      {
        name: "yyy",
        id: "1",
      },
    ],
    customerLOB: {
      code: "A2",
    },
  },
  {
    conditions: [
      {
        name: "zzzz",
        id: "1",
      },
    ],
    customerLOB: {
      code: "A3",
    },
  },
];

const array2 = [
  {
    conditions: [
      {
        name: "mmmm",
        id: "1",
      },
    ],
    customerLOB: {
      code: "A1",
    },
  },
  {
    conditions: [
      {
        name: "nnnn",
        id: "1",
      },
    ],
    customerLOB: {
      code: "A2",
    },
  },
  {
    conditions: [
      {
        name: "oooo",
        id: "1",
      },
    ],
    customerLOB: {
      code: "A3",
    },
  },
];

const finalList = [];

array1.map((retrieveCondition) => {
  array2.find((item) => {
    if (retrieveCondition.customerLOB.code === item.customerLOB.code) {
      finalList.push({
        ...retrieveCondition.conditions,
        ...item.conditions,
      });
    }
  });
});

console.log(finalList);




This JSON is invalid. Also it would be good to have the code as runnable snippet, so we can better understand the problem.

Edited the JSON.

With your latest edit, you have implemented the bug fix I suggested, but now the statement "But instead of 3 results , I am getting 6 results." is not true anymore. Your question is now really confusing. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

@JSON Derulo My query is , if the code matches, then append the conditions array of array2 to array , so the end result will have only 3 array of objects,(first one -conditions array of objects for A1 code, second one- conditions array of objects for A2 code and so on)

You are pushing an array containing both objects to the final list, which isn't what you are looking for. Instead, you want to combine two objects to a single one. So instead of [...], you should use {...}.
Before:
finalList.push([
  ...retrieveCondition.conditions,
  ...item.conditions,
]);

After:
finalList.push({
  ...retrieveCondition.conditions,
  ...item.conditions,
});

Updated snippet:


const array1 = [
  {
    conditions: [
      {
        name: "xxx",
        id: "1",
      },
    ],
    customerLOB: {
      code: "A1",
    },
  },
  {
    conditions: [
      {
        name: "xxx",
        id: "1",
      },
    ],
    customerLOB: {
      code: "A2",
    },
  },
  {
    conditions: [
      {
        name: "xxx",
        id: "1",
      },
    ],
    customerLOB: {
      code: "A3",
    },
  },
];

const array2 = [
  {
    conditions: [
      {
        name: "xxx",
        id: "1",
      },
    ],
    customerLOB: {
      code: "A1",
    },
  },
  {
    conditions: [
      {
        name: "xxx",
        id: "1",
      },
    ],
    customerLOB: {
      code: "A2",
    },
  },
  {
    conditions: [
      {
        name: "xxx",
        id: "1",
      },
    ],
    customerLOB: {
      code: "A3",
    },
  },
];

const finalList = [];

array1.map((retrieveCondition) => {
  array2.find((item) => {
    if (retrieveCondition.customerLOB.code === item.customerLOB.code) {
      finalList.push({
        ...retrieveCondition.conditions,
        ...item.conditions,
      });
    }
  });
});

console.log(finalList);




Pushing to array is not the problem here, the problem is I am getting duplicate result of every object

@Nancy Please read my answer again. This is happening because (by accident?) you are pushing and spreading arrays to the final list, while you want to push and spread objects. I edited your question and created a runnable snippet, where the issue is visible. Also I added a fixed version of the snippet, where only 3 objects are present, which is what you want, as per question.
